# Reescribir archivo csv reasignando columnas

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un archivo csv (llamémoslo entrada.csv) que tiene la siguiente estructura, pero que contiene un número muy grande de filas:

```
ID;Texto_1;Puntos_1;Texto_2;Puntos_2
1;"Hola mundo dos";33;"Hola mundo tres";90
2;"Adiós mundo dos";44;"Adiós mundo tres";100
```

Qiero conseguir otro archivo csv (llamémoslo salida.csv) que reorganice las columnas así:

```
    ID;Campo;Puntos;
    1;Texto_1;33
    1;Texto_2;90
    2;Texto_1;44
    2;Texto_2;100
```

No parece tan fácil como a priori pensaba. He intentado generar listas que luego pegar en el nuevo csv file, pero me pregunto si hay una manera de transcribirlo directamente de manera directa. Agradezco comentarios como siempre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jugando un poco con cada fila no es complicado, la clave está en escribir dos filas de salida por cada una de entrada:

```
import csv

with open("entrada.csv") as in_file, open("salida.csv", "w") as out_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(in_file, dialect='unix', delimiter=";",
                            quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    writer = csv.writer(out_file, dialect='unix', delimiter=";",
                            quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    writer.writerow(["ID", "Campo", "Puntos"])
    for row in reader:
        writer.writerows(((row["ID"], "Texto_1", row["Puntos_1"]),
                          (row["ID"], "Texto_2", row["Puntos_2"])))
```

En todo momento trabajamos con iteradores creando el csv de salida a medida que leemos el de origen, sin cargar ninguno de los csv en memoria.

La salida para tu ejemplo es la deseada:

> ID;Campo;Puntos
>   1;Texto_1;33
>   1;Texto_2;90
>   2;Texto_1;44
>   2;Texto_2;100

Comment: Gracias @FJSevilla.

Answer (score 1):

Esta es la forma simple y tosca de procesar la lista y generar la salida que buscas, no tiene mucha ciencia detrás:

```
import pprint

texto = """ID;Texto_1;Puntos_1;Texto_2;Puntos_2
1;"Hola mundo dos";33;"Hola mundo tres";90
2;"Adiós mundo dos";44;"Adiós mundo tres";100"""

filas = [l.split(";") for l in texto.split("\n")]
del filas[0] # eliminamos el Header

newlist = list()
for l in filas:
  newlist.append([l[0], 'Texto_1', l[2]])
  newlist.append([l[0], 'Texto_2', l[4]])

pprint.pprint(newlist)
```

La salida:

```
[['1', 'Texto_1', '33'],
 ['1', 'Texto_2', '90'],
 ['2', 'Texto_1', '44'],
 ['2', 'Texto_2', '100']]
```

Básicamente recorremos cada fila y la dividimos en dos registros en  una nueva lista.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. No obstante, no disponemos de una variabla denominada "texto" sino de un archivo csv. La idea no sería obtener una lista, sino un csv cuyas columnas están separadas por puntos y coma, como en el ejemplo. No sé si estoy mainterpretando la respuesta. He editado la pregunta para ver si se entiende mejor.

Comment: @pyring, la variable `texto` es un ejemplo que puse para procesar el contenido de tu pregunta. Lo que deberías es leer el archivo tal como entiendo lo estás haciendo y contar con una lista de líneas. Luego sigues mi ejemplo. De todas formas la respuesta de FJSevilla es mucho mejor. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias @Patricio Moracho. Tus respuestas me son de gran ayuda para progresar.